# Writing an image to file in Tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to insert a line into this function such that when it decodes a jpeg, it writes the jpeg to a file (I am doing this for sanity checking purposes).

```
def decoded_jpeg(image_buffer, scope=None):
    with tf.name_scope(values=[image_buffer], name=scope,
                 default_name='decode_jpeg'):

        fname = tf.constant('2.jpg')
        image_buffer = tf.write_file(fname, image_buffer)
        image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(image_buffer, channels=3)

        image = tf.image.convert_image_dtype(image, dtype=tf.float32)
        return image
```

The code above does not error out, but it does not have the desired effect, because it tf.write_file returns an op and not a tensor string. I'm wondering how I should rewrite the above code to make this work properly.

The rest of the code can be seen here (Its the Inception CNN): https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/inception/inception

Comment: Did you try running the op returned by `tf.write_file`? in your `sess.run()` call, add `image_buffer`. That should trigger the saving of your image file.

Comment: The thing is this function is buried in a somewhat deep recursive call. Do you recommend any way to get this op to my sess.run? I am currently going to try making some sort of global list.